# Janusgraph libs cant communicate with hbase in kerberos environment(Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name)

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos, janusgraph, apache-spark-2.3

I am getting "Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name" when attempting to connect to habse with janusgraph in a kerberos hadoop cluster

First off a little environmental info -
OS: 7.6.1810
Java: 1.8.0_191-b12
Spark: 2.3.2.3.1.0.78-4
YARN: 2.5.0
Hbase: 2.0.2.3.1.0.78-4
Hadoop: 3.1.1.3.1.0.78-4
Kerberos: 5 version 1.15.1
Janusgraph: 0.4.0

I did kinit and test the bundled gremlin client to ensure the graph.properties for the env works. It was able to connect up create a simple test graph, add some vertices, restart and retrieve the stored data. So cool the bundled copy works.

For laziness/simplicity I decided to load the spark-shell with janusgraph libs. While attempting to connect to the same graph it started throwing kerberos errors.

First thought being maybe its a hadoop/spark lib/conf conflict(pretty typical). So built out a very simple and barebones java app in an attempt to see if it would work. Got the same errors as spark.

Spark Invocations -
First attempt:

```
spark-shell \
--conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true \
--conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true \
--conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true \
--jars /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml,groovy-console-2.5.6.jar,javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar,netty-buffer-4.1.25.Final.jar,RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar,groovy-groovysh-2.5.6-indy.jar,javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar,netty-codec-4.1.25.Final.jar,activation-1.1.jar,groovy-json-2.5.6-indy.jar,jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar,netty-common-4.1.25.Final.jar,airline-0.6.jar,groovy-jsr223-2.5.6-indy.jar,jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar,netty-handler-4.1.25.Final.jar,antlr-2.7.7.jar,groovy-swing-2.5.6.jar,jbcrypt-0.4.jar,netty-resolver-4.1.25.Final.jar,antlr-3.2.jar,groovy-templates-2.5.6.jar,jboss-logging-3.1.2.GA.jar,netty-transport-4.1.25.Final.jar,antlr-runtime-3.2.jar,groovy-xml-2.5.6.jar,jcabi-log-0.14.jar,noggit-0.6.jar,aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar,gson-2.2.4.jar,jcabi-manifests-1.1.jar,objenesis-2.1.jar,apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar,guava-18.0.jar,jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar,ohc-core-0.3.4.jar,apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar,hadoop-annotations-2.7.7.jar,je-7.5.11.jar,org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-csv-1.0-r706900_3.jar,api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar,hadoop-auth-2.7.7.jar,jersey-client-1.9.jar,oro-2.0.8.jar,api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar,hadoop-client-2.7.7.jar,jersey-client-2.22.2.jar,osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar,asm-3.1.jar,hadoop-common-2.7.7.jar,jersey-common-2.22.2.jar,paranamer-2.6.jar,asm-5.0.3.jar,hadoop-distcp-2.7.7.jar,jersey-container-servlet-2.22.2.jar,picocli-3.9.2.jar,asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar,hadoop-gremlin-3.4.1.jar,jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.2.jar,protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar,asm-commons-5.0.3.jar,hadoop-hdfs-2.7.7.jar,jersey-core-1.9.jar,py4j-0.10.7.jar,asm-tree-5.0.3.jar,hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.7.jar,jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar,pyrolite-4.13.jar,asm-util-5.0.3.jar,hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.7.jar,jersey-json-1.9.jar,reflections-0.9.9-RC1.jar,astyanax-cassandra-3.10.2.jar,hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.7.jar,jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.2.jar,reporter-config-base-3.0.0.jar,astyanax-cassandra-all-shaded-3.10.2.jar,hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.7.jar,jersey-server-1.9.jar,reporter-config3-3.0.0.jar,astyanax-core-3.10.2.jar,hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.7.jar,jersey-server-2.22.2.jar,scala-library-2.11.8.jar,astyanax-recipes-3.10.2.jar,hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.7.jar,jets3t-0.7.1.jar,scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar,astyanax-thrift-3.10.2.jar,hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.7.jar,jettison-1.3.3.jar,scala-xml_2.11-1.0.5.jar,audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar,hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.7.jar,jetty-6.1.26.jar,servlet-api-2.5.jar,avro-1.7.4.jar,hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.7.jar,jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar,sesame-model-2.7.10.jar,avro-ipc-1.8.2.jar,hamcrest-core-1.3.jar,jetty-util-6.1.26.jar,sesame-rio-api-2.7.10.jar,avro-mapred-1.8.2-hadoop2.jar,hbase-shaded-client-2.1.5.jar,jffi-1.2.16-native.jar,sesame-rio-datatypes-2.7.10.jar,bigtable-hbase-1.x-shaded-1.11.0.jar,hbase-shaded-mapreduce-2.1.5.jar,jffi-1.2.16.jar,sesame-rio-languages-2.7.10.jar,caffeine-2.3.1.jar,hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar,jline-2.14.6.jar,sesame-rio-n3-2.7.10.jar,cassandra-all-2.2.13.jar,high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar,jna-4.0.0.jar,sesame-rio-ntriples-2.7.10.jar,cassandra-driver-core-3.7.1.jar,high-scale-lib-1.1.4.jar,jnr-constants-0.9.9.jar,sesame-rio-rdfxml-2.7.10.jar,cassandra-thrift-2.2.13.jar,hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar,jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar,sesame-rio-trig-2.7.10.jar,checker-compat-qual-2.5.2.jar,hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar,jnr-posix-3.0.44.jar,sesame-rio-trix-2.7.10.jar,chill-java-0.9.3.jar,hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar,jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar,sesame-rio-turtle-2.7.10.jar,chill_2.11-0.9.3.jar,hppc-0.7.1.jar,joda-time-2.8.2.jar,sesame-util-2.7.10.jar,commons-cli-1.3.1.jar,htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar,jsch-0.1.54.jar,sigar-1.6.4.jar,commons-codec-1.7.jar,htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar,json-20090211_1.jar,slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar,commons-collections-3.2.2.jar,httpasyncclient-4.1.2.jar,json-simple-1.1.jar,slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar,commons-configuration-1.10.jar,httpclient-4.4.1.jar,json4s-ast_2.11-3.5.3.jar,snakeyaml-1.11.jar,commons-crypto-1.0.0.jar,httpcore-4.4.1.jar,json4s-core_2.11-3.5.3.jar,snappy-java-1.0.5-M3.jar,commons-httpclient-3.1.jar,httpcore-nio-4.4.5.jar,json4s-jackson_2.11-3.5.3.jar,solr-solrj-7.0.0.jar,commons-io-2.3.jar,httpmime-4.4.1.jar,json4s-scalap_2.11-3.5.3.jar,spark-core_2.11-2.4.0.jar,commons-lang-2.5.jar,ivy-2.3.0.jar,jsp-api-2.1.jar,spark-gremlin-3.4.1.jar,commons-lang3-3.3.1.jar,jackson-annotations-2.6.6.jar,jsr305-3.0.0.jar,spark-kvstore_2.11-2.4.0.jar,commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,jackson-core-2.6.6.jar,jts-core-1.15.0.jar,spark-launcher_2.11-2.4.0.jar,commons-math3-3.2.jar,jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar,jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar,spark-network-common_2.11-2.4.0.jar,commons-net-1.4.1.jar,jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar,junit-4.12.jar,spark-network-shuffle_2.11-2.4.0.jar,commons-pool-1.6.jar,jackson-datatype-json-org-2.6.6.jar,kryo-shaded-4.0.2.jar,spark-tags_2.11-2.4.0.jar,commons-text-1.0.jar,jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar,leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar,spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.0.jar,compress-lzf-1.0.0.jar,jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar,libthrift-0.9.2.jar,spatial4j-0.7.jar,concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar,jackson-module-paranamer-2.6.6.jar,log4j-1.2.16.jar,stax-api-1.0-2.jar,crc32ex-0.1.1.jar,jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.6.6.jar,logback-classic-1.1.3.jar,stax-api-1.0.1.jar,curator-client-2.7.1.jar,jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar,logback-core-1.1.3.jar,stax2-api-3.1.4.jar,curator-framework-2.7.1.jar,jamm-0.3.0.jar,lucene-analyzers-common-7.0.0.jar,stream-2.7.0.jar,curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar,janusgraph-all-0.4.0.jar,lucene-core-7.0.0.jar,stringtemplate-3.2.jar,disruptor-3.0.1.jar,janusgraph-berkeleyje-0.4.0.jar,lucene-queries-7.0.0.jar,super-csv-2.1.0.jar,dom4j-1.6.1.jar,janusgraph-bigtable-0.4.0.jar,lucene-queryparser-7.0.0.jar,thrift-server-0.3.7.jar,ecj-4.4.2.jar,janusgraph-cassandra-0.4.0.jar,lucene-sandbox-7.0.0.jar,tinkergraph-gremlin-3.4.1.jar,elasticsearch-rest-client-6.6.0.jar,janusgraph-core-0.4.0.jar,lucene-spatial-7.0.0.jar,unused-1.0.0.jar,exp4j-0.4.8.jar,janusgraph-cql-0.4.0.jar,lucene-spatial-extras-7.0.0.jar,uuid-3.2.jar,findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar,janusgraph-es-0.4.0.jar,lucene-spatial3d-7.0.0.jar,validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar,gbench-0.4.3-groovy-2.4.jar,janusgraph-hadoop-0.4.0.jar,lz4-1.3.0.jar,vavr-0.9.0.jar,gmetric4j-1.0.7.jar,janusgraph-hbase-0.4.0.jar,lz4-java-1.4.0.jar,vavr-match-0.9.0.jar,gprof-0.3.1-groovy-2.4.jar,janusgraph-lucene-0.4.0.jar,metrics-core-3.0.2.jar,woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar,gremlin-console-3.4.1.jar,janusgraph-server-0.4.0.jar,metrics-core-3.2.2.jar,xbean-asm6-shaded-4.8.jar,gremlin-core-3.4.1.jar,janusgraph-solr-0.4.0.jar,metrics-ganglia-3.2.2.jar,xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar,gremlin-driver-3.4.1.jar,javapoet-1.8.0.jar,metrics-graphite-3.2.2.jar,xml-apis-1.3.04.jar,gremlin-groovy-3.4.1.jar,javassist-3.18.0-GA.jar,metrics-json-3.1.5.jar,xmlenc-0.52.jar,gremlin-server-3.4.1.jar,javatuples-1.2.jar,metrics-jvm-3.2.2.jar,zookeeper-3.4.6.jar,gremlin-shaded-3.4.1.jar,javax.inject-1.jar,minlog-1.3.0.jar,zstd-jni-1.3.2-2.jar,groovy-2.5.6-indy.jar,javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar,netty-3.10.5.Final.jar,groovy-cli-picocli-2.5.6.jar,javax.json-1.0.jar,netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar
```

Second attempt(less libs):

```
spark-shell  \
--conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true \
--conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true \
--conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true \
--jars /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml,gremlin-core-3.4.1.jar,gremlin-driver-3.4.3.jar,gremlin-shaded-3.4.1.jar,groovy-2.5.7.jar,groovy-json-2.5.7.jar,javatuples-1.2.jar,commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar,commons-configuration-1.10.jar,janusgraph-core-0.4.0.jar,hbase-shaded-client-2.1.5.jar,janusgraph-hbase-0.4.0.jar,high-scale-lib-1.1.4.jar
```

Java attempt:

```
java \
-cp /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml:/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml:hbase-shaded-client-2.1.5.jar:janusgraph-hbase-0.4.0.jar:janusgraph-core-0.4.0.jar:commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:gremlin-driver-3.4.3.jar:groovy-2.5.7.jar:javatuples-1.2.jar:commons-configuration-1.10.jar:gremlin-core-3.4.1.jar:gremlin-shaded-3.4.1.jar:groovy-json-2.5.7.jar:high-scale-lib-1.1.4.jar:Janusgraph_Ingestion.jar:../janusgraph-0.4.0-hadoop2/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:../janusgraph-0.4.0-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:../janusgraph-0.4.0-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar:../janusgraph-0.4.0-hadoop2/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:../janusgraph-0.4.0-hadoop2/lib/guava-18.0.jar:../janusgraph-0.4.0-hadoop2/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:../janusgraph-0.4.0-hadoop2/lib/commons-io-2.3.jar:../janusgraph-0.4.0-hadoop2/lib/htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar \
Entry
```

As far as code being executed in the spark-shell or java

```
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;
val g = JanusGraphFactory.open("/home/devuser/janusgraph-0.4.0-hadoop2/conf/janusgraph-hbase.properties").traversal()
```

Also tried adding the below before attempting to open the graph

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;

val conf = new Configuration();

conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(null);
```

Including graph connect config for completeness

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=hosta.example.com:2181,hostb.example.com:2181,hostc.example.com:2181
storage.hbase.table=JgraphTest
storage.hbase.ext.zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-secure
storage.batch-loading=false
java.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf
storage.hbase.ext.hbase.security.authentication=kerberos
storage.hbase.ext.hbase.security.authorization=true
storage.hbase.ext.hadoop.security.authentication=kerberos
storage.hbase.ext.hadoop.security.authorization=true
storage.hbase.ext.hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal=hbase/_HOST@HDPDEV.example.com
ids.block-size=10000
ids.renew-timeout=3600000
storage.buffer-size=10000
ids.num-partitions=10
ids.partition=true
schema.default=none
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
```

Expected result would be a usable traversal object
Actual result below

```
19/10/18 11:40:30 TRACE NettyRpcConnection: Connecting to hostb.example.com/192.168.1.101:16000
19/10/18 11:40:30 DEBUG AbstractHBaseSaslRpcClient: Creating SASL GSSAPI client. Server's Kerberos principal name is null
19/10/18 11:40:30 TRACE AbstractRpcClient: Call: IsMasterRunning, callTime: 4ms
19/10/18 11:40:30 DEBUG RpcRetryingCallerImpl: Call exception, tries=7, retries=16, started=8197 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=java.io.IOException: Call to hostb.example.com/192.168.1.101:16000 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name, details=, see https://s.apache.org/timeout, exception=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: java.io.IOException: Call to hostb.example.com/192.168.1.101:16000 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionImplementation.java:1175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionImplementation.java:1234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.getMaster(ConnectionImplementation.java:1223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:3089)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getHTableDescriptor(HBaseAdmin.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor(HBaseAdmin.java:529)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseAdmin1_0.getTableDescriptor(HBaseAdmin1_0.java:105)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureTableExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:726)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getLocalKeyPartition(HBaseStoreManager.java:537)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getDeployment(HBaseStoreManager.java:376)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getFeatures(HBaseStoreManager.java:418)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.builder.GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.build(GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.java:51)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:161)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:132)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:79)
    at $line22.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:26)
    at $line22.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:31)
    at $line22.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:33)
    at $line22.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:35)
    at $line22.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $line22.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:39)
    at $line22.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $line22.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
    at $line22.$read.<init>(<console>:45)
    at $line22.$read$.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $line22.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line22.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line22.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line22.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:415)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:923)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:904)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Call to hostb.example.com/192.168.1.101:16000 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.wrapException(IPCUtil.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.onCallFinished(AbstractRpcClient.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$100(AbstractRpcClient.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.callComplete(Call.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.setException(Call.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.BufferCallBeforeInitHandler.userEventTriggered(BufferCallBeforeInitHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:329)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:315)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.userEventTriggered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1377)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:329)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:315)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireUserEventTriggered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:929)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection.failInit(NettyRpcConnection.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection.saslNegotiate(NettyRpcConnection.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection.access$800(NettyRpcConnection.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection$3.operationComplete(NettyRpcConnection.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection$3.operationComplete(NettyRpcConnection.java:261)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:500)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:479)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:82)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:306)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:341)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AbstractHBaseSaslRpcClient.<init>(AbstractHBaseSaslRpcClient.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.NettyHBaseSaslRpcClient.<init>(NettyHBaseSaslRpcClient.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.NettyHBaseSaslRpcClientHandler.<init>(NettyHBaseSaslRpcClientHandler.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection.saslNegotiate(NettyRpcConnection.java:194)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I feel like an idiot. Sooo apparently the answer was actually a really simple deal. Appears that the gremlin client will work fine when just using storage.hbase.ext.hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal but when using the libs out side of that storage.hbase.ext.hbase.master.kerberos.principal is needed as well. Well as far as this things are working on to the next set of problems I made for myself lol.

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!